# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a functionが出てしまう

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

test.jsの「.on('show.bs.modal', function (e)」箇所で以下のようなエラーが出ており、
モーダルは表示されるのですが、モーダルのタイトルが書き換わりません…。
onの使い方、bootstrapのモーダルの書き方がおかしいのでしょうか？

```
test.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM31857 test.js:2)
    at Function.<anonymous> (VM31855 jquery.min.js:19)
    at Function.each (VM31855 jquery.min.js:12)
    at Function.ready (VM31855 jquery.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM31855 jquery.min.js:19)
```

●test.js

```
$(function () {

  $("#testModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var recipient = button.data("name");
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find(".modal-title").text(recipient);
    }, 300);                        
  });

});
```

●index.html

```
～
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-name="test" data-target="#testModal">表示</button>
～
    <div class="modal" style="z-index: 1500" id="testModal" 
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-show="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&#215;</span><span class="sr-only">閉じる</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">タイトル</h4>
          </div><!-- /modal-header -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="recipient">内容</p>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal -->

～
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test.js`のfunctionにはミスがありましたが、それ以外は問題ないと思います。

下記のスニペットを実行して確認してください。

```js
$(function() {
  $("#testModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var modal = $(e.target);
      var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
      var recipient = button.data("name");
      modal.find(".modal-title").text(recipient);
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-name="test" data-target="#testModal">表示</button>
<div class="modal" style="z-index: 1500" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-show="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&#215;</span><span class="sr-only">閉じる</span>
            </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">タイトル</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="recipient">内容</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！いただいた内容で表示されたため、何がだめなのかと思っていたのですが、<script src=～で指定するjsの読み込む順序を変えるだけでした。ありがとうございます。助かりました。